# Html Select dropdown not populate option in Mobile Chrome : Angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs, mobile-chrome

In our application we are using both Jquery and Angularjs on some modules.
I'm facing some weird issue, html `select` dropdown is not populating options in 
mobile browser especially in `mobile chrome`. Because of `angualr-arina`.

> Please check this snippet in Mobile chrome browser

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<select>
<option value='1'>One</option>
</select>
```

Any idea on enable/disable `ng-arina` module on page load. Or how to handle this problem ?